# Error while using date picker value as parameters in LocalDate constructor

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker

I am using DatePicker to get the LocalDate then convert to String.
But everyTime I try to get the year ,the month, and the days from DatePicker then use them as parameters in LocalDate Constructor. The program crashed. If I just manually typing the year, the month, and the day in constructor of LocalDate it works fine in TableView

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
{
    roomTypeChoice.setValue("Select");
    roomTypeChoice.setItems(roomTypeList);

    //setting the cell of each Column that propertyValueFactory should make sure that 
    //the variable name should be consisted with memeber variable name otherwise the tableview can not 
    //display the value
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
    checkInCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("checkInDate"));
    checkOutCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("checkOutDate"));      
    phoneCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("phoneNumber"));
    addressCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("address"));
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));



}    

@FXML
private void checkIn(ActionEvent event)  
{

    //get the Check in date convert to Date Object from DatePicker
    LocalDate checkInLocalDate=LocalDate.of(checkInDatePicker.getValue().getYear(), checkInDatePicker.getValue().getMonthValue(), checkInDatePicker.getValue().getDayOfMonth());
    String checkInDate=checkInLocalDate.toString();
    System.out.println(checkInLocalDate.toString()+"");
    Customer customer=new Customer(firstNameTextField.getText().trim(),lastNameTextField.getText().trim(),checkInDate,checkInDate
    ,phoneTextField.getText().trim(),addressTextField.getText().trim(),emailTextField.getText().trim());


    tableView.getItems().add(customer);



}
```

I am hoping to rid off this issue that brothers me a lot.

Comment: May I ask why you're creating a `LocalDate` from the values of another? Instances of `LocalDate` are immutable, which makes copying unnecessary. And can you please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue? _Include the stack trace of the exception in your question as well_. I can't reproduce the problem using OpenJDK 12 with JavaFX 12—though without the actual error I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this

```
LocalDate localDate = checkInDatePicker.getValue();

int day = localDate.getDayOfMonth();
int month = localDate.getMonthValue();
int year = localDate.getYear();
```